# Jupiter отказывается подключать библиотеки

Tags: python, библиотеки, root, notebook

Господа, подскажите новичку...
Ситуация в том, что на работе заблокирована возможность установки сторонних программ и портативных с флеш-устройств.
Нашёл такую вещь, как Jupiter, который позволяет работать в Python через браузер. Там прописано, что можно подключать библиотеки к нему, такие как panda или matplotlib.
Однако, когда я попробовал в файле прописать строку: `!pip install pandas` как сказано в учебниках, то Jupiter мне выдал ошибку: "get_ipython().system('pip install pandas')". Честно, не понимаю, что делаю не так, вроде делаю всё как написано.
И ещё хотелось бы узнать, можно ли таким образом через браузер подключить к Jupiter например модули tkinter, pygame и работать вот таким образом без установки на компьютер?
Признателен за помощь.

Comment: Это точно вся ошибка? И где у вас `Jupyter` - там же, где запрещено что-то ставить? Тогда вряд ли что-то удастся сделать.

Comment: попробуйте устанавливать модули локально с ключом --user, например, pip3 install --user модуль # это установит модуль в ваш домашний каталог

Comment: "мне выдал ошибку: "get_ipython().system('pip install pandas')"" - это не ошибка, это только строка, в которой возникла ошибка. "можно ли таким образом через браузер подключить к Jupiter например модули tkinter, pygame и работать вот таким образом без установки на компьютер?" - если у вас Jupyter запущен на сервере, а не на локальном компьютере, то нет.